# Logearse con un campo que no sea EMAIL con identityUser y netCore 2.1

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Buen día.

Estoy haciendo un login con JWT, Roles y claims, usando netCore 2.1

Tengo una semana apenas tocando .net, cualquier corrección es bien recibida.

Ya puedo loguearme y expedir el token con mi configuración. El asunto es que ese login funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] Usuario userInfo)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userInfo.Email,
                                                                      userInfo.Password,
                                                                      isPersistent: false,
                                                                      lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return await BuildTokenAsync(userInfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
```

Al adentrarme en el metodo PasswordSignInAsync, pues pide esos parametros.
**¿Como puedo implemenar la verificación del login usando otro campo que no sea el Email?**

Dejo mi modelo de Usuario para que vean como esta constituido.

Gracias de antemano.

```
public class Usuario
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserNumber { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public List<Area> Area { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta fue mi solución.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserModel userInfo)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userAsp =  _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserNumber == userInfo.UserNumber);

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userAsp.Email,
                                                                      userInfo.Password,
                                                                      isPersistent: false,
                                                                      lockoutOnFailure: false);

                Console.Out.WriteLine();
                if (userAsp != null & result.Succeeded)
                {
                    userInfo.Role = userAsp.Role;
                    userInfo.UserNumber = userAsp.UserNumber;
                    userInfo.UserName = userAsp.UserName;
                    userInfo.Email = userAsp.Email;

                    return await BuildTokenAsync(userInfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt. 2");
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
```

En mi variable userAsp busco mi Usuario por el UserNumber (Que no es el id, es mas bien el típico número de empleado).

Si me aseguro que mi usuario no es null (osea, que existe) y que a su vez pasa el SUCCESS del PasswordSignInAsync, entonces, se loguea normalmente.

Acepto críticas y sugerencias.

Comment: Añadiría que valides que "userAsp" no sea nulo antes de invocar PasswordSignInAsync  (PasswordSignInAsync Te podría dar error si "userAsp" es nulo) y aprovecha para que si es nulo, lances una excepción/error.

Comment: Modifica tu codigo de respuesta porque no va de acuerdo con tu texto de UserNumber

Comment: ¿A que te refieres Miguel Zarate?